# How to track email is opened or not, email is delivered or not, email bounced or not?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mailchimp

I am trying to build an email marketing tools. where i can track my customers actions, whether they opened the email or not and email delivered or not.
I will send some HTML template in the email.

So i want to know the concept of this how i can develop this type of protocol ?
I am using backend as NodeJs, Nodemailer and for frontend i am using react js.

I am trying to develop a prototype like [mailchimp](https://mailchimp.com/).

So can anyone suggest me how i can achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can by editing your letter :**

1. **Create a Tracking Pixel:**

Create a small, transparent image (1x1 pixel) and host it on a server. This image will be loaded when the recipient opens the email.

1. **Insert the Tracking Pixel in Your Email:**

Include an HTML image tag in your email with the source pointing to the hosted tracking pixel. This is the part that will be invisible to the recipient.

html:

```
<img src="https://your-tracking-pixel-url.com/pixel.png" width="1" height="1" alt="tracking pixel">
```

1. **Capture the Request on Your Server:**

On your server, log or process requests for the tracking pixel. Each time the image is loaded, it indicates that the email has been opened.

Comment: did you use any generative AI at all in the writing of this answer post?

Answer (score 0):

Nodemailer already tells you if an error occurred during sending an email.

```
transporter.sendMail({
    from: 'sender@example.com',
    to: 'recipient@example.com',
    subject: 'Message',
    text: 'I hope this message gets delivered!'
}, (err, info) => {
    // check for errors here
    console.error(err);
    console.log(info);
});
```

For tracking if email is opened or not:

You can possibly add a small hidden image to the HTML body and when that image is loaded from your server, you can know at least if customers are opening their emails.

Comment: thank you for your reply.Is there any other way to do this to track open?

Comment: Not that I know of. This is the standard method of tracking emails. And it does have some limitations, like if images are blocked by the email client by default, then email openings won't be registered.